# Выделение интервалов из списка

Tags: python, list

Есть, например, такой список:

```
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Мне нужно выделить из него:

```
[[1], [-1], [1], [1], [1,2]]
```

Как это можно быстро сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**способ 1:**

делайте в лоб просто:

```
arr = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]

res = []
tmp = []
for i in arr:
    if i == 0:
        if tmp:
            res.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(i)

if tmp:
    res.append(tmp)

print(res)
```

**способ 2:**

а можно не в лоб и с извратом :)

```
arr = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]

res = [[int(j) for j in i.split(',') if j != ''] for i in (str(arr)[1:-1].replace(' ', '') + ',').split('0,') if i != '']

print(res)
```

**способ 3:**

тот же способ 2, только чуть с другого бока и покороче:

```
res = [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in (' ' + ' '.join(map(str, arr))).split(' 0') if i != '']
```

Comment: от ваших list comprehension путается вестибулярный аппарат :)

Comment: @Jack_oS, добавил упрощённый вариант :)))

Comment: в `if` можно вместо `tmp != [] ` написать `tmp`

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
res = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x:x!=0) if k]
```

res:

```
[[1], [-1], [1], [1], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: а почему вы используете `numpy`, если можно использовать обычный список?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - мой косяк, оборачивал в ndarray для другого способа, забыл убрать.

Comment: Отличный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы может добавлять элементы, пока они не равны 0:

```py
x= [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]

ans=[]
tmp=[]
for el in x:
    if el==0:
        if len(tmp)>0:
            ans.append(tmp)
        tmp=[]
    else:
        tmp.append(el)
if len(tmp)>0:
    ans.append(tmp)
```

`ans` будет представлять из себя `[[1], [-1], [1], [1], [1,2]]`

Comment: а вы попробуйте `[0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]` ;-)

Comment: @Zhihar, спасибо, подправил:)